# Change Contact in undelete trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects, undelete

I'm experiencing a weird issue with undelete trigger on Contact record.

```
// trigger
trigger triggerContact on Contact (after undelete) {
    for(Contact contact : Trigger.new) {
        if (contact.My_Custom_Field__c != 'aaa') {
            contact.My_Custom_Field__c = 'bbb';
        }
    }
}
// test
Contact c = new Contact(
       LastName = 'Contact',
       My_Custom_Field__c = 'aaa'
);
insert c;
delete c;

Test.startTest();
undelete c;
Test.stopTest();

c = [SELECT My_Custom_Field__c FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Contact'];
System.assert(c.My_Custom_Field__c == 'bbb');
```

I got the following error: System.FinalException: Record is read-only.
My question: if it's possible to change a contact field in undelete trigger. The same approach Works fine for custom object.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the correct error. records are always read only in after context in trigger I am sure same will not work for custom object as well. you need to modify your code in following way.

```
// trigger
trigger triggerContact on Contact (after undelete) {
    list<contact> lstcontact = new list<contact>();
    for(Contact contact : Trigger.new) {
        if (contact.My_Custom_Field__c != 'aaa') {

            lstcontact.add(new contact(id=contact.id,My_Custom_Field__c ='bbb'));
        }
    }

    update lstcontact;
}
```